# Cassandra high cpu

Tags: linux, cassandra, garbage-collection, cpu

I do have a cluster of 150 nodes, Cassandra 2.2.x, 8 cpu and 64 GB ram.
From time to time couple of my nodes have 100 % cpu but the rest of the nodes looks just fine.

When I have 100 % cpu:

My [tpstats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUWxO.jpg)

No compactions are pending.

```
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-05-12 18:03:51,636 GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 262ms.  G1 Eden Space: 1291845632 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 10237756144 -> 7451103472; G1 Survivor Space: 419430400 -> 134217728;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-05-12 18:03:54,130 GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 286ms.  G1 Eden Space: 1577058304 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 7451103472 -> 4596956920; G1 Survivor Space: 134217728 -> 150994944;
INFO  [Service Thread] 2018-05-12 18:03:57,652 GCInspector.java:284 - G1 Young Generation GC in 213ms.  G1 Eden Space: 1560281088 -> 0; G1 Old Gen: 4596956920 -> 4135583472; G1 Survivor Space: 150994944 -> 134217728;
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:172351] 2018-05-12 18:21:29,098 AutoSavingCache.java:399 - Saved CounterCache (258640 items) in 298 ms
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:172352] 2018-05-12 18:21:29,979 AutoSavingCache.java:399 - Saved KeyCache (788252 items) in 1282 ms
```

It is not the same node some other days I have different nodes who has 100 % cpu, any ideas?

[Heap size Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMvSG.jpg)

```
Table: abc
                SSTable count: 14
                Space used (live): 3 960 499 258
                Space used (total): 3960499258
                Space used by snapshots (total): 0
                Off heap memory used (total): 8427312
                SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.25806487155056185
                Number of keys (estimate): 379760
                Memtable cell count: 172086
                Memtable data size: 1253025
                Memtable off heap memory used: 4654441
                Memtable switch count: 192
                Local read count: 33923975
                Local read latency: 15.081 ms
                Local write count: 30595833
                Local write latency: 0.144 ms
                Pending flushes: 0
                Bloom filter false positives: 18478
                Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
                Bloom filter space used: 1523216
                Bloom filter off heap memory used: 1523104
                Index summary off heap memory used: 459327
                Compression metadata off heap memory used: 1790440
                Compacted partition minimum bytes: 30
                Compacted partition maximum bytes: 4055269
                Compacted partition mean bytes: 11408
                Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
                Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1
                Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 178.40981886703793
                Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 258



Table: xyz
                SSTable count: 8
                Space used (live): 2034316302
                Space used (total): 2034316302
                Space used by snapshots (total): 0
                Off heap memory used (total): 4289964
                SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.24435625500089553
                Number of keys (estimate): 260117
                Memtable cell count: 133822
                Memtable data size: 832669
                Memtable off heap memory used: 2215708
                Memtable switch count: 175
                Local read count: 10034316
                Local read latency: 11.653 ms
                Local write count: 27984185
                Local write latency: 0.075 ms
                Pending flushes: 0
                Bloom filter false positives: 261009
                Bloom filter false ratio: 0.04762
                Bloom filter space used: 1007024
                Bloom filter off heap memory used: 1006960
                Index summary off heap memory used: 200632
                Compression metadata off heap memory used: 866664
                Compacted partition minimum bytes: 61
                Compacted partition maximum bytes: 5839588
                Compacted partition mean bytes: 8883
                Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
                Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1
                Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 28.292941014323677
                Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 60



Table: zzz
                SSTable count: 8
                Space used (live): 1542111866
                Space used (total): 1542111866
                Space used by snapshots (total): 0
                Off heap memory used (total): 14022908
                SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.5677972573793397
                Number of keys (estimate): 8670916
                Memtable cell count: 0
                Memtable data size: 0
                Memtable off heap memory used: 0
                Memtable switch count: 0
                Local read count: 0
                Local read latency: NaN ms
                Local write count: 0
                Local write latency: NaN ms
                Pending flushes: 0
                Bloom filter false positives: 0
                Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
                Bloom filter space used: 10623352
                Bloom filter off heap memory used: 10623288
                Index summary off heap memory used: 3157452
                Compression metadata off heap memory used: 242168
                Compacted partition minimum bytes: 36
                Compacted partition maximum bytes: 268650950
                Compacted partition mean bytes: 242
                Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): NaN
                Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 0
                Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): NaN
                Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 0
```

Now the load has dropped. Just to compare after load abc table stats:

```
Table: abc
                SSTable count: 14
                Space used (live): 3960499258
                Space used (total): 3960499258
                Space used by snapshots (total): 0
                Off heap memory used (total): 24792685
                SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.25806487155056185
                Number of keys (estimate): 380267
                Memtable cell count: 780522
                Memtable data size: 3746628
                Memtable off heap memory used: 21019814
                Memtable switch count: 192
                Local read count: 33927339
                Local read latency: 9.319 ms
                Local write count: 30598848
                Local write latency: 0.093 ms
                Pending flushes: 0
                Bloom filter false positives: 18478
                Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
                Bloom filter space used: 1523216
                Bloom filter off heap memory used: 1523104
                Index summary off heap memory used: 459327
                Compression metadata off heap memory used: 1790440
                Compacted partition minimum bytes: 30
                Compacted partition maximum bytes: 4055269
                Compacted partition mean bytes: 11408
                Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
                Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 1
                Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 179.0
                Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 179
```

Comment: with `nodetool cfstats` or `nodetool tablestats` whats the largest maximum partition size and number of tombstones per read you have? Can you share tablestats/tablehistograms? Things like wide partitions or tombstones can generate a lot of garbage on heap. Whats your heap settings? GCs are setup to try to use 100% cpu so if GC thrashing that will keep processor pegged.

Comment: Hi Chris, I have added table info and heap size image, there are tombstones...

Comment: also added table stats after the load drops

Comment: So looking back at logs, 250ms gc every 4 secs isnt bad. So might not be GC related. Your partitions seem good sized and not too many tombstones or cells per read. TPStats does show its likely reads though, you can verify that with https://github.com/aragozin/jvm-tools and `ttop`. `ttop` output from sjk would help debug. Without knowing more about your data load id recommend switching `abc` to leveled compaction strategy just from your read/write ratio which would bring down sstable touches and cpu cost per read. You can set that with jmx on a single host to test before applying cluster wide.

Comment: fwiw can set it with something like : `java -jar sjk.jar mx -p CASSPID -ms -b org.apache.cassandra.db:type=ColumnFamilies,keyspace=KEYSPACE,columnfamily=TABLE -f CompactionParametersJson \{"class":"LeveledCompactionStrategy","sstable_size_in_mb":"256"\}` or https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/213370546-Change-CompactionStrategy-and-sub-properties-via-JMX